# Date-picker and angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for my `datetime` input fields. These input fields also have a `ng-model`.

Example:

```
<input id="period-start" type="datetime" ng-model="periodStart">
<script>$('#period-start').datetimepicker()</script>
```

When I pick a date, the model doesn't change. 
What must I do to make it work?

Comment: You should use angular version of it.
https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to replace the bootstrap datetime picker, so inspired by Theodore's answer, I wrote my own directive to "hook it in."

```
export function dateTimePickerDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
      var format = $(element).data('format') || 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm';

      var picker = element.datetimepicker({
        format: format,
        locale: 'sv'
      })

      element.on('dp.change', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          var date = new Date(event.date.toString());
          ctrl.$setViewValue(date);
        });
      });

      ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        var date = moment(value);
        if (date.isValid()) {
          return date.format(format);
        }

        return '';
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not binded on UI elements matching DOM selectors. You need to wrap your code on a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead.

Here is an example using [Angular UI datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/4ht8y4nw/) and another one using [jQuery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/)

The second example is quite easy to follow:

```
angular
    .module('App',['ui.date'])
    .directive('customDatepicker',function($compile){
        return {
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'custom-datepicker.html',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                dateOptions: '='
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller){
                var $button = $element.find('button');
                var $input = $element.find('input');
                $button.on('click',function(){
                    if($input.is(':focus')){
                        $input.trigger('blur');
                    } else {
                        $input.trigger('focus');
                    }
                });
            }    
        };
    })
```

And on your view:

```
<input type="text" ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd" ng-model="ngModel" ui-date="{ minDate: -20, maxDate: '+1M +10D' }"/>
```